# how to change label into dropdown when size reduce?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

[image]
hello 
I am trying to change the layout of my screen when my  large screen move to small screen .When I have large screen  I show my menu option on header as a label .which i am able to make .But when I reduce the screen size to 600px width I need to show this on dropdown the menu options

how will I do this ?
I search on google and find using  media query it is possible .I try to implement this . but I got event but how it is possible

here is my code and images

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpGKYO

[image]

```
    #menubar li {
        display: inline;
        padding:0.5em;
        font-size:1.5em;
        color :red
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        body {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    }
#menubar{
  float:right;
  display: block;
  position:relative;
}

#menubarCont {
  width: 100%;
  float: right ;
  right:10em;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a *working* demo? Otherwise it's not interesting to fix it in order to help you. But yes, it's possible but you will need to change markup a little because you can't transform list into select.

Comment: How about keeping different containers for menus and playing with their visibility using `Media Queries` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need media queries to hide the menu you don't want to show. Here's a simple example: (resize browser window to test)

```css
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: orange;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .large {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .small {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="large">
        Large screen menu
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <select>
        <option>menu item 1</option>
        <option>menu item 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[And here's a Fiddle too](http://jsfiddle.net/ejbm82fv/)

Comment: Was about to type the same answer. The simple solution is just to include both in the code and show the correct one depending on media query.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing my two cents. The answer from @Schlaus is preferred way to do it and the way I would also do it. Here is a code pen I found of a way to do it without having to code the menu twice in the markup - it's a good reference for those that are curious for other alternative ways of getting it done using JQuery.

http://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/GlBed

---

**HTML**

```
<nav> 

  <h1>This menu turns into a <code>&lt;select&gt;</code> when window is less than 960px to conserve space.</h1>

  <ul> 
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#books">Books</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#support">Support</a></li> 
  </ul>

</nav>
```

---

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  font: 300 21px "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
      border: 1px solid red;
      background: red;
    }
    &:active {
      background: blue;
    }
  }
  select {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  nav {
    ul {
      display: none;
    }
    select {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
}
```

---

**JQuery**

```
// DOM ready
$(function() {

  // Create the dropdown base
  $("<select />").appendTo("nav");

  // Create default option "Go to..."
  $("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
    "value"   : "",
    "text"    : "Go to..."
  }).appendTo("nav select");

  // Populate dropdown with menu items
  $("nav a").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
      "value"   : el.attr("href"),
      "text"    : el.text()
    }).appendTo("nav select");
  });

   // To make dropdown actually work
   // To make more unobtrusive: http://css-tricks.com/4064-unobtrusive-page-changer/
  $("nav select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  });

});
```

---

Hope this clears up a few things for others and hopefully helps someone else in the future

Cheers